# Objective-C implementation of Shape Context algorithm (Image Matching)?

Tags: objective-c, image

There is a very cool sounding technique called Shape Context matching, which can be used in an Image Recognition application to match an "unknown image" against a known "image library."    There are numerous descriptions of the concept documented on the web (mostly all variations of the same original paper), for example:  http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html

I found a JAVA implementation and a MATLAB implementation of the algorithm described in the paper, but I cannot find an objective-c implementation. Anyone know if there is any objective-c code out there, anywhere, implementing these techniques?  I sure would like to take advantage of it, rather than trying to write that stuff myself!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Java implementation you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MacosxInstallGuide).  It is implemented in C so it can be used in obj-c pretty easily.

Comment: Ah, ok.  When I first read the OpenCV main page I saw references to Linux and Windows, but nothing about Mac or objective-c.  But upon closer reading I see that "portions" should work under Mac OS X.  So I'll try to install it and see if the portion I need is one of those.

Right now I am doing my development on the Mac ... but eventually (if it all works) I will want to build the app for iphone.  If I use an OpenCV component will that hinder my ability to build for iphone?

Comment: So I have installed OpenCV, and successfully done a simple test.  I will now delve a little deeper, and see what I can come up with.

Comment: opencv does not have implementation of shape context based matching.

Comment: opencv 3.0 has a c++ implementation of shape context based matching, but it doesn't have proper bindings for all languages yet.

Comment: [OpenCV Documenation on Shape Context](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html), [OpenCV Implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/shape/src/sc_dis.cpp), [OpenCV Example Usage](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/samples/cpp/shape_example.cpp)

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find an interesting c++ implementation (for non-commercial usage, didn't check it yet.. see the downloads):
http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhengyf/PointMatching.htm

Comment: emm... the above cpp-code is partly buggy BUT IN GENERAL VERY GOOD SUPPORT TO REIMPLEMENT IT (using e.g. OpenCV)! Found bug is e.g.: log10 in shapecontext.cpp (wrong) used instead of log2 (!! correct for log-polar coordinates, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-polar_coordinates).. and I'm not sure if everywhere point p = q is excluded (should be) etc..

Comment: why should log10 be wrong? The OpenCV implementation also uses log10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently searching for a Java implementation of the algorithm. Could you please provide a link to the implementation you found?

The original matlab code can be downloaded at:
www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html

I also found a C# implementation:
http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7465&lngWId=10